# ¿Cómo trabajar con múltiples dataframes de forma iterativa?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente problema, dado mis múltiples dataframes:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(MASS)
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)


df41 = read.table("2014_1.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df42 = read.table("2014_2.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df43 = read.table("2014_3.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df44 = read.table("2014_4.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df51 = read.table("2015_1.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df52 = read.table("2015_2.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df53 = read.table("2015_3.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df54 = read.table("2015_4.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df61 = read.table("2016_1.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df62 = read.table("2016_2.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df63 = read.table("2016_3.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df64 = read.table("2016_4.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df71 = read.table("2017_1.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df72 = read.table("2017_2.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df73 = read.table("2017_3.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df74 = read.table("2017_4.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df81 = read.table("2018_1.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df82 = read.table("2018_2.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df83 = read.table("2018_3.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df84 = read.table("2018_4.csv",sep=";",header=T)
df91 = read.table("2019_1.csv",sep=";",header=T)
```

quiero encontrar alguna forma practica de poder llamar a cada uno de estos dataframes sin tener que crear un código para cada uno, como cuando en una lista en python uno llama a un elemento de esa lista con el indice de su posición y crea una variable a la que le se le asigna ese valor (intente ponerlos todos en un vector y me creo un dataframe con todas las columnas unidas y no quiero eso). El fin de esto, es que quiero crear nuevos dataframes (unir filas) mediante un filtro de nombres. Cada uno de estos tiene una columna de nombres: a,b,c,... y quiero que todas las filas con nombre a sean un solo dataframe y asi sucesivamente, considerando que no manejo muy bien el uso for, while, if, else en r y que los ejemplos que busque no me ayudaron mucho

Comment: puedes guardarlos a todos en un lista de R. Ve la función list(). Pe. datos<-list(df41,df42) luego puedes llamar al primer df con datos[[1]]

Comment: Gracias estimado

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R` tiene a las listas como una de sus (principales) estructuras de datos, así que podrías hacer lo que mencionas que se puede hacer en Python sin problemas.

De hecho no necesitarías usar mucho `for`, `while` o estructuras de control por el estilo, en `R` la familia de funciones `*apply` se encarga de iterar sobre listas de una manera muy simple.

Hacer una lista de data.frame es muy fácil, en tu caso te sugeriría hacer "manualmente" la lista de archivos que quieres leer. También puedes usar la función `list.files()` para hacer una lista de todos los archivos en una ubicación que coinciden con una expresión regular.

Con esa lista de nombres de archivos (cada elemento de la lista de una cadena de caracteres) podrías usar `lapply()` para aplicar la función `read.table()` a cada elemento de la lista (nombres de archivo)  y recibir como output una lista de data.frame.

A esos data.frame que están dentro de la lista los puedes llamar (técnicamente, hacer un subconjunto)  por número de índice y así irlos manejando.

Sí todos los data.frame tienen las mismas columnas entonces lo más simple es "colapsarlos"  a un único data.frame y después manejarlos así directamente.

En `R` la función para unir objetos por filas es `rbind`, y puedes aplicarla con la función `Reduce()` para que vaya uniendo a cada elemento de la lista.

Por último puedes crear data.frame separados haciendo un subset para cada letra de la columna `nombre` o separarlos en una lista con `split()`.

Sin los archivos no es fácil darte un código que funcione, aquí va un intento a partir de la información que está en la pregunta:

```
# Creo un vector con los nombres de archivo
archivos <- c("2014_1.csv",
              "2014_2.csv",
              "2014_3.csv",
              "2014_4.csv",
              "2015_1.csv",
              "2015_2.csv",
              "2015_3.csv",
              "2015_4.csv",
              "2016_1.csv",
              "2016_2.csv",
              "2016_3.csv",
              "2016_4.csv",
              "2017_1.csv",
              "2017_2.csv",
              "2017_3.csv",
              "2017_4.csv",
              "2018_1.csv",
              "2018_2.csv",
              "2018_3.csv",
              "2018_4.csv",
              "2019_1.csv")

#Uso lapply() con una función lambda para leer todos los archivos y organizar
#el output en una lista. x se evalúa como cada elemento de la lista archivos

lista_df <- lapply(archivos, function (x) read.table(x, sep=";",header=T)

#Si todos los data.frame tienen las mismas columnas puedo reducir la lista 
#a un solo data.frame

df_unido <- Reduce(rbind, lista_df)
```

Si se dan los supuestos deberías tener el df completo y después dependiendo del caso ver como hacer el subset por nombres.

Si puedes leer inglés te sugiero consultar la ayuda de `lapply()` con `help("lapply"))`.

Saludos!

Comment: Ya ya, mil gracias, no sabía del comando list(), lo empezaré a trabajar altiro, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia:

UN complemento para tener las listas de una forma auotmatica:

Se crea un lugar de donde se va a tomar la informacion en este caso esta en el uusario jj en one drive

Almacen=('C:/Users/jj/OneDrive')

Hacemos uso de os
base_guardar=('C:/Users/7eric/OneDrive/Instacredit/BD/MC/depuradas/')
lista=os.listdir(base_guardar)
lista

Con esto te debe crear una lista de todos los archivos que tienes en esa carpeta y lo guarda con un objeto lista lo cual ayudaria con el post de arriba ya que no tienes que crear manualmente la lista  archivos

Saludos

Comment: Perdon no observe que estabas en R , esto funciona para python

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/351059)